# Node.js http.get in loop only getting last item

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, streaming

I'm looping over a set of URLs trying to get their HTML, but it only works for the last one in the list.  The "NOT WRITING YET" console.log fires for everything in the urls array, as expected, but the console.logs after that only fire for the last one.  They are all valid URLs and "res.on('error'....." returns nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for (var z in urls) {
    var getURL = urls[z];
    var copyURL = 'copies/'+getURL;

    if (copyURL.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
        var copyURLArr = copyURL.split('/');
    } else {
        var copyURLArr = [copyURL];
    }

    var copyFile = copyURLArr.pop();

    var runningDirs = '';
    for (var i in copyURLArr) {
        if (runningDirs.length > 0) runningDirs += '/';
        runningDirs += copyURLArr[i];
        if (!require('fs').existsSync(runningDirs)) {
            exec('mkdir '+runningDirs);
        }
    }
console.log('NOT WRITING YET: '+urlPrefix+getURL);
    require('http').get(urlPrefix+getURL, function(res) {
console.log(urlPrefix+getURL);
        res.on('data', function(data) {
console.log(copyURL);
            require('fs').createWriteStream(copyURL, {flags:'a+'}).write(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `console.log(urlPrefix+getURL);` the value will always be for the last url because when the callback is called the values of these variables will be from the last time they got assigned which is the last iteration in the loop.

instead make the request in a separate function like

```
function doRequest(url, copyURL) {
   require('http').get(url, function(res) {
        console.log(url);
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(copyURL);
            require('fs').createWriteStream(copyURL, {flags:'a+'}).write(data);
        });
    });
}
```

and then call this function with `doRequest(urlPrefix+getURL, copyURL)` then check if the problem still exists

Comment: Thanks for that!  Yeah, it was a silly mistake, but I haven't done a whole lot with Javascript and I forgot about that.  I'm still not totally clear on why it works out the way it does, though.  I understand why my console.log was coming out as it was, but shouldn't the parameter being passed to http.get still be good since that's not part of a callback and should be passing the value existing on that iteration?

Comment: sure, but the copyURL that you write to is not going to be the correct one

Comment: Right.  Yeah, not being completely exhausted today it's common sense...sorry about that!  Someone really needs to tell me not to code when I'm half asleep.